# Encontrar e remover palavras de vários arrays

Tags: php, regex

Tenho alguns arrays que vem do banco de dados, e gostaria de remover ocorrências de palavras neles, por exemplo, a string na `$title`

```
$title = "Eles foram com José procurar alguma coisa";

$bad_words = array('foram','prOcuRar','.....');
```

Como posso remover todos os termos que estão na frase, com base na variável `$bad_words`, de forma `case-insensitve`, usando Regex para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! Você pode utilizar a função [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-ireplace.php), com ela você faz a substituição com ignore case. Veja um exemplo de obter o resultado que espera:

```
<?php

$bad_words = array('foram','prOcuRar','.....');
$title = "Eles foram com José procurar alguma coisa";

foreach($bad_words as $bad_word)
{
    $title = str_ireplace($bad_word, '', $title);
}

print_r($title); //Eles com José alguma coisa

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - palavras isoladas  [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/NhDhgE)

Computando a diferença dos dois arrays com a função  `array_udiff` e sem diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas com   `strcasecmp`

```
$bad_words = array('foram','prOcuRar','.....');
$title = "Eles foram com NGTHM4R3 procurar alguma coisa para remover ocorrências de palavras";

$title = implode(" ", array_udiff(explode(" ", $title), $bad_words, 'strcasecmp'));

print_r($title);
```

> 2 - Sequências de palavras   [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/yfdo9e)

```
$bad_words = array('foram','prOcuRar alguma coisa','alguma','Ponte que partiu');
$title = "Eles foram com NGTHM4R3 procurar alguma coisa pedir ajuda para remover palavras ou sequência de palavras tal como Ponte que partiu";

$title = str_ireplace($bad_words,'',$title);
$title= preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $title);

echo $title;
```

DOCS:

[array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-udiff.php)

[strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcasecmp.php)

[str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-ireplace.php)

Comment: Leo, uma observação, caso a palavra de $bad_words sejam composta, não faria identificação por causa do explode. Exemplo, se 'prOcuRar' fosse 'prOcuRar alguma'.

Comment: @Bruno Rigolon, isso não está claro na pergunta, do jeito que foi perguntado subentende-se tratar de palavras isoladas. Mas vou aproveitar e editar a resposta.

Comment: Concordo Leo, era só uma observação. ;)

Comment: @Bruno Rigolon de qq forma valeu pois desenvolvi outra opção :)